# Kotlin and AOSP Development

Tags: android, kotlin, android-source

I am new to AOSP development and wanted to know the following:

1. Can the Kotlin be used for AOSP development for Automotive Domain?
2. If yes, are there any examples for the same?
3. If No, reason why Kotlin cannot be used?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi it is possible to use Kotlin for your automotive android project.
in android studio when you choose android automotive from templates you can choose default language and Kotlin is one of options.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick response. :) This below link says otherwise and it is very old but anything changed after this?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60856774/aosp-kotlin-support/64279956#64279956

Comment: I  am sure you can use Kotlin although there might be a third-party library which limits you. https://github.com/leventarican/cookbook-android it can make sense for you